# Need help in formal grammar for the $L = \{wcw : w \in \{a,b\}^\ast\}$

Tags: formal-languages

I can't create formal grammar for the language like

$wcw$ where $w$ is the word in $\{a,b\}^\ast$ and $c$ is just a letter

Thanks!

Comment: Michael: In case the hint in my post was not sufficient to help you solve this, feel free to [ping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) me; so that we can discuss this further.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (but I did not check all details, so I apologize if I've overseen some problem there):

Would you be able to make a grammar in which this would be a derivation?

$S \Rightarrow^* ABBS \Rightarrow^* A_1B_1B_1S_1A_3B_3B_3 \Rightarrow^* abbcabb$

Of course, $S$, $A$, $B$, $A_1$, $B_1$, $A_2$, $B_2$, $A_3$, $B_3$ are non-terminals, $a$, $b$ are terminals.

EDIT:
I've added two more non-terminals. (In the approach I have in mind I will need them to distinguish whether the letter has already "moved" to the right half.)

---

I've tried too google a little, mainly for the reason that I did not want put energy into writing up a solution if it was already given elsewhere.

Searching for ["formal language" grammar "wcw"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22formal+language%22+grammar+%22wcw%22) and similar phrases led me to [this paper](http://users.utu.fi/aleokh/papers/conj_bool_programming.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506155807/http://users.utu.fi/aleokh/papers/conj_bool_programming.pdf)). Some grammar for this language is given there. But it is not the type of grammar you're looking for - it's a [Boolean grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_grammar). But since the author mentions that this is one of the *standard examples of non-context-free constructs*, this suggest that this should probably not be too difficult and this example could occur in some standard textbooks.

The fact that it is not context-free should be provable using [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma); a complete proof of this fact is given in [Johan Jeuring, Doaitse Swierstra: Grammars and Parsing](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/gont/diktaat.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20171118114840/http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/gont/diktaat.pdf)), which is basically a collection of solved exercises (with solutions).

Answer (score 0):

A solution:
$$\begin{align*}
\Sigma & \to \mathtt{c} & \tag{1} \\
\Sigma & \to i \mathtt{c} i & \mathrm{for} \: i \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{2} \\
\Sigma & \to i C_{j} A_{i} S_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{3} \\
C_{i} A_{j} & \to D_{i} A_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{4} \\
D_{i} A_{j} & \to D_{i} B_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{5} \\
B_{i} A_{j} & \to B_{i} B_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{6} \\
B_{i} S_{j} & \to B_{i} X_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{7} \\
B_{i} S_{j} & \to B_{i} Y_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{8} \\
B_{i} X_{j} & \to T_{i} X_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{9} \\
B_{i} Y_{j} & \to F_{i} Y_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{10} \\
B_{i} T_{j} & \to T_{i} T_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{11} \\
B_{i} F_{j} & \to F_{i} F_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{12} \\
D_{i} T_{j} & \to \mathtt{a} C_{i} T_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{13} \\
D_{i} F_{j} & \to \mathtt{b} C_{i} F_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{14} \\
C_{i} T_{j} & \to C_{i} Z_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{15} \\
C_{i} F_{j} & \to C_{i} Z_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{16} \\
Z_{i} T_{j} & \to Z_{i} Z_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{17} \\
Z_{i} F_{j} & \to Z_{i} Z_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{18} \\
Z_{i} X_{j} & \to Z_{i} A_{\mathtt{a}} S_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{19} \\
Z_{i} Y_{j} & \to Z_{i} A_{\mathtt{b}} S_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{20} \\
Z_{i} A_{j} & \to A_{i} A_{j} & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{21} \\
S_{i} & \to i & \mathrm{for} \: i \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{22} \\
A_{i} j & \to i j & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{23} \\
C_{i} j & \to i \mathtt{c} j & \mathrm{for} \: i , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} \tag{24}
\end{align*}$$

The idea of this **context-sensitive grammar** is similar to that of 4-stroke engine:

1. the sentential form
   $$i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} C_{j} A_{i_{1}} A_{i_{2}} \cdots A_{i_{n}} S_{j}$$
   becomes either
   $$ i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} D_{j} B_{i_{1}} B_{i_{2}} \cdots B_{i_{n}} S_{j} \tag{go to 2} $$
   by $\left( 4 \right)$, $\left( 5 \right)$ and $\left( 6 \right)$ or
   $$ i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} j \mathtt{c} i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} j \tag{end} $$
   by $\left( 22 \right)$, $\left( 23 \right)$ and $\left( 24 \right)$;
2. the sentential form
   $$i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} D_{j} B_{i_{1}} B_{i_{2}} \cdots B_{i_{n}} S_{j}$$
   becomes either
   $$ i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} D_{j} T_{i_{1}} T_{i_{2}} \cdots T_{i_{n}} X_{j} \tag{go to 3} $$
   by $\left( 7 \right)$, $\left( 9 \right)$ and $\left( 11 \right)$ or
   $$ i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} D_{j} F_{i_{1}} F_{i_{2}} \cdots F_{i_{n}} Y_{j} \tag{go to 4} $$
   by $\left( 8 \right)$,  $\left( 10 \right)$ and $\left( 12 \right)$;
3. the sentential form
   $$i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} D_{j} T_{i_{1}} T_{i_{2}} \cdots T_{i_{n}} X_{j}$$
   becomes
   $$ i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} \mathtt{a} C_{j} Z_{i_{1}} Z_{i_{2}} \cdots Z_{i_{n}} X_{j} \tag{go to 5} $$
   by $\left( 13 \right)$, $\left( 15 \right)$ and $\left( 17 \right)$;
4. the sentential form
   $$i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} D_{j} F_{i_{1}} F_{i_{2}} \cdots F_{i_{n}} Y_{j}$$
   becomes
   $$ i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} \mathtt{b} C_{j} Z_{i_{1}} Z_{i_{2}} \cdots Z_{i_{n}} Y_{j} \tag{go to 6} $$
   by $\left( 14 \right)$, $\left( 16 \right)$ and $\left( 18 \right)$;
5. the sentential form
   $$i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} \mathtt{a} C_{j} Z_{i_{1}} Z_{i_{2}} \cdots Z_{i_{n}} X_{j}$$
   becomes
   $$ i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} \mathtt{a} C_{j} A_{i_{1}} A_{i_{2}} \cdots A_{i_{n}} A_{\mathtt{a}} S_{j} \tag{go to 1} $$
   by $\left( 19 \right)$ and $\left( 21 \right)$;
6. the sentential form
   $$i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} \mathtt{b} C_{j} Z_{i_{1}} Z_{i_{2}} \cdots Z_{i_{n}} Y_{j}$$
   becomes
   $$ i_{1} i_{2} \cdots i_{n} \mathtt{b} C_{j} A_{i_{1}} A_{i_{2}} \cdots A_{i_{n}} A_{\mathtt{b}} S_{j} \tag{go to 1} $$
   by $\left( 20 \right)$ and $\left( 21 \right)$;

where $ n \geq 1 $, $ i_{1} , i_{2} , \cdots i_{n} , j \in \left\{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \right\} $.

An example:
$$\begin{align*}
\Sigma & \implies \mathtt{a} C_{\mathtt{b}} A_{\mathtt{a}} S_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 3 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} D_{\mathtt{b}} A_{\mathtt{a}} S_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 4 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} D_{\mathtt{b}} B_{\mathtt{a}} S_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 5 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} D_{\mathtt{b}} B_{\mathtt{a}} X_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 7 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} D_{\mathtt{b}} T_{\mathtt{a}} X_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 9 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} C_{\mathtt{b}} T_{\mathtt{a}} X_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 13 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} C_{\mathtt{b}} Z_{\mathtt{a}} X_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 15 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} C_{\mathtt{b}} Z_{\mathtt{a}} A_{\mathtt{a}} S_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 19 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} C_{\mathtt{b}} A_{\mathtt{a}} A_{\mathtt{a}} S_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 21 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} D_{\mathtt{b}} A_{\mathtt{a}} A_{\mathtt{a}} S_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 4 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} D_{\mathtt{b}} B_{\mathtt{a}} A_{\mathtt{a}} S_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 5 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} D_{\mathtt{b}} B_{\mathtt{a}} B_{\mathtt{a}} S_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 6 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} D_{\mathtt{b}} B_{\mathtt{a}} B_{\mathtt{a}} Y_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 8 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} D_{\mathtt{b}} B_{\mathtt{a}} F_{\mathtt{a}} Y_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 10 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} D_{\mathtt{b}} F_{\mathtt{a}} F_{\mathtt{a}} Y_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 12 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} C_{\mathtt{b}} F_{\mathtt{a}} F_{\mathtt{a}} Y_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 14 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} C_{\mathtt{b}} Z_{\mathtt{a}} F_{\mathtt{a}} Y_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 16 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} C_{\mathtt{b}} Z_{\mathtt{a}} Z_{\mathtt{a}} Y_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 18 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} C_{\mathtt{b}} Z_{\mathtt{a}} Z_{\mathtt{a}} A_{\mathtt{b}} S_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 20 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} C_{\mathtt{b}} Z_{\mathtt{a}} A_{\mathtt{a}} A_{\mathtt{b}} S_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 21 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} C_{\mathtt{b}} A_{\mathtt{a}} A_{\mathtt{a}} A_{\mathtt{b}} S_{\mathtt{b}} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 21 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} C_{\mathtt{b}} A_{\mathtt{a}} A_{\mathtt{a}} A_{\mathtt{b}} \mathtt{b} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 22 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} C_{\mathtt{b}} A_{\mathtt{a}} A_{\mathtt{a}} \mathtt{b} \mathtt{b} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 23 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} C_{\mathtt{b}} A_{\mathtt{a}} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} \mathtt{b} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 23 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} C_{\mathtt{b}} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} \mathtt{b} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 23 \right) \\
& \implies \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} \mathtt{b} \mathtt{c} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{a} \mathtt{b} \mathtt{b} & \mathrm{by} \: \left( 24 \right)
\end{align*}$$